# Кто может наглядно показать как собрать массив из данных юзеров и передать его в переменную?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вообщем на сайте 1000 юзеров, у каждого в таблице wp_usermeta есть поле user_company.
По id автора поста я смотрю его user_company

```
$author_company = get_user_meta( $post->post_author, 'user_company', true );
//получаю $author_company = 'Samsung';
```

Также у всех юзеров есть поле user_token_bot которое содержит какой-то id

```
$user_token_bot = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'user_token_bot', true );
//$user_token_bot = '1111'; например
```

Теперь мне надо собрать массив всех этих user_token_bot но только у тех юзеров у которых user_company тоже Samsung как и компания автора поста и поместить этот массив в переменную.

```
$tokens = ['1111','2222','3333','4444'] ///вот в таком виде.
```

Я тут не буду описывать че я пытался сделать, че я только не делал, и через запросы к базе и через

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
      'key'     => 'user_company',
      'value'   => $author_company,
      'compare' => '=',
  ),
     )
) );
```

в итоге ничего не получается даже на этапе сбора, не то что формирования готового результата в новый массив.

Помогите наглядно собрать код из этих условий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если я правильно понял что вам нужно то запрос может должен выглядеть вот так

```
function get_users_token( $company_name ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $prepare_query = $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT um1.meta_value
         FROM $wpdb->usermeta AS um1
         JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS um2 ON um1.user_id = um2.user_id
         WHERE um1.meta_key = 'user_token_bot' AND um2.meta_key = 'user_company' AND um2.meta_value = %s",
        $company_name
    );

    return wp_list_pluck( $wpdb->get_results( $prepare_query ), 'meta_value' );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но бьет крит.ошибку это первое, а второе wpdb->postmeta здесь для чего? Нужно сделать выборку по таблице wp_usermeta и postmeta  и post_id вообще не требуются. из Post_id  узнаю только компанию автора поста,чтобы получить название компании. Дальше сам пост не играет никакой роли. Главное выбрать  user_token_bot у всех у кого компания та же что и у автора.

Comment: Это все утро, изменил запрос. Какая у вас ошибка?

Comment: Просто 500-ую ошибку бьет и все. Но я  хотя бы уже примерно понимаю в какую сторону ковырять.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)
в FROM ${wpdb->usermeta} AS um1

Comment: Ещё раз обновил код, попробуйте так

Comment: Ошибка исчезла, страница загружается. Только не пойму как посмотреть массив. через print_r ничего не выводит

Comment: возможно у вас нет совпадений и вы получаете пустой массив

Comment: Ну я в правильном направлении копаю?
$company_name = 'Samsung'; //это название компании по которой я собираю токены
$tokens =  get_users_token( $company_name); 
print_r($tokens);

Comment: О да я их получил))))
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1987375) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1446300) )

Comment: можно еще прогнать результат через wp_list_pluck чтобы получить простой массив, посмотрите в ответе, я добавил этот фильтр

Comment: Абалдеть именно так мне и нужно было. Теперь осталось понять как его оформить чтобы в переменной были значения в '1446300', '1987375' в ковычках и через запятую

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php это вам поможет)

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Уже на этом этапе это квантовый скачек. Неделя бессонных ночей чтоб сделать эту выборку.